# install4j throws error message during install

Tags: java, soapui, install4j, exe4j

I'm unable to install anything, which installer is using `install4j`. I got following error message in text file during install:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:737)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig.finishBatch(AbstractBeanConfig.java:51)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.registerScreens(ContextImpl.java:695)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:83)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen
```

System information:

> java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   exe4j.moduleName=C:\installers\SoapUI-x32-5.5.0.exe
>   exe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_installers_soapui-x32-5.5.0.exe
>   java.vm.version=25.181-b13 java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   java.runtime.version=1.8.0_181-b13

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software enabled that could quarantine JAR files?

Comment: @IngoKegel: No, there aren't any additional antivirus on that machine.

Comment: Please start with the argument /create-i4j-log from the command line and send the log file to support@ej-technologies.com

Comment: @IngoKegel : It is an exe file. How could I start it with this flag?

Comment: Open a terminal, and execute `c:\installers\installers_soapui-x32-5.5.0.exe /create-i4j-log`

Answer (score 1):

Put the exe file in the following location: c:\Temp\SoapUI_5-5-0.exe
Open a CMD window and navigate to this location by typing the following command: *cd c:\Temp*
Type the following two commands in the CMD window:
Commands:

set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=
After this:

Execute the Soap install file via the CMD window simply by typing in the name of the execution file: SoapUI_5-5-0.exe
The install went perfectly and I am still not sure why or what the reason is behind the fix.